# Safari failed send cookie - http: named cookie not present

Tags: cookies, go, safari

My backend is Golang. I use the following code to to set an http cookie to the browser, like so:

```
cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "user", Value: strCookie, MaxAge: 86400, Secure: true, HttpOnly: true}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

In the next http session, I use the following code to try to read the cookie:

```
cookieUser, err := r.Cookie("user")
```

It works with Chrome, Firefox, but Safari failed to send the cookie back to the backend, therefore the Golang tried to read the cookie, it shows the error message:

```
http: named cookie not present
```

So I'm wondering whether this is a Safari specific bug or there's any problem in my program.

Comment: Whether cookies can be used is a browser setting. Browsers can disallow the use of cookies in which case any cookie that is sent from server using the `"Set-cookie"` header will not get stored, and you won't see any cookie back from such a browser.

Comment: The `Secure: https` field is invalid: it should be either true or false.

Comment: @elithrar sorry https should be a bool variable which should be evaluate true in this case.

Comment: @icza, I saw the cookie being sent back in Chrome console, but in Safari, it   is not sent. I have the feeling this might be a browser specific problem. But I'm not quite sure.

Comment: What happens if you set `Secure: false` - further, can you confirm that this is all served/visited via localhost?

Comment: @elithrar, I checked again. When Secure is false, it doesn't work, when Secure is true, it works. This happens only with Safari. I apologize previously I said https evaluated to true, which was incorrect. Chrome and Firefox work well. It's not via localhost. It's via a domain name.

Comment: You'll need to share more of your program or disclose your domain. It's unlikely to be a bug in Safari but instead in the cookie. The value may be too large, the Path not set and/or failing cross-origin. Chrome & Safari still share a lot of cookie related code.

Comment: @elithrar They are actually http://solidtunnel.com and https://solidtunnel.com. The one with https works well, but the one with http doesn't work with Safari.

Comment: OK, after creating an account in Chrome (v47 dev) I can replicate the issue in Safari v9.0 if I visit the website over HTTPS first, log in, and then try to visit after over vanilla HTTP. The `user` cookie with `Secure: true` will not be issued back over vanilla HTTP. Chrome v47 also acts in the same manner, which is to be expected: you don't want a subsequent visit over HTTP to send sensitive cookies that may be MITM'ed. For a VPN service you should be setting HSTS headers and forcing HTTPS anyway.

Comment: @elithrar thanks. I think you made things start to be clear now. I'm using Chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit). It issues back the user cookie over vanilla HTTP. Does it mean lower version Chrome's behavior is incorrect, it actually should not issue back?

Comment: Thank you @elithrar. I have redirected all http requests to https. Would you post your last comment as an answer so that I can mark it as answered?

Comment: "Secure" cookies must not and are not sent back over plain http by any browser. That's the whole idea behind "secure". I'd bet you are doing something wrong if this does not work.

Comment: @Volker, thanks. I have completely redirected all http request to https.